# Create custom Windows 10 notification boxes

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

in Windows 10 there are those gray notification boxes in the lower right corner. They come when you plug in a USB, when Updates were installed or when a virus was found by windows defender.

My question: How can i create these things? (with a custom message), if possible in vbs or batch as than they would be the easy to call from all programming languages. I know that this is possible as these boxes will also popup when someone pokes you in teamspeak.

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: Do you mean [notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (have been around for ages)?

Comment: Nope; thats the same like in Windows 7. I mean the dark-gray popups, they will be in a rectangle in the lower right corner and dont look like a speech bubble. I will look for pictures, if i find one ill post it.

Comment: theres a picture: http://media.askvg.com/articles/images5/Windows_10_Updates_Notification.png  note that here the box is blue, because it will change depending on the style you have set for your pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are toast notifications and they come from Universal Windows Apps.

Hear are couple of posts:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/08/toast-notification-and-action-center-overview-for-windows-10.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/09/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10.aspx
- https://www.whitebyte.info/programming/c/how-to-make-a-notification-from-a-c-desktop-application-in-windows-10

I don't think you can create them any other way than by creating a universal app.

Comment: `I don't think you can create them any other way than by creating a universal app.` <- this is sad, if still valid today. I'll keep on looking.

Answer (score 17):

An easier way to achieve windows8/10 notification toast is with Powershell.

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing")
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$notify.visible = $true
$notify.showballoontip(10,"New Chat!","You have received New Chat!",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```

execute above script in powershell console.

Comment: Looked in everywhere and this is the only answer that worked for me. Thank you 