# How to show Windows 10 notification toast from VBA

Tags: vba, powershell, notifyicon

I'd like to know the easiest way to show notification toast in windows 10 from VBA.

I didn't found a good answer to this. I found a really simple way to create notifications from PowerShell [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42605444/12676192). But I can't get it to work from VBA because I didn't find a way to execute this in one line using WScript.Shell.

I tried several ways to accomplish that but i didn't succeed. Below you can find my last attempt:

```
Public Sub Notify_Test()

Dim WsShell     As Object: Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim strCommand  As String

strCommand = """powershell.exe"" ^ "
strCommand = strCommand & "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(""System.Windows.Forms"")"
strCommand = strCommand & "; [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname(""System.Drawing"")"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify.visible = $true"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify.showballoontip(10,""New Chat!"",""You have received New Chat!"",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)"

WsShell.Run strCommand

End Sub
```

I'd like to avoid writing a .ps1 file. Can someone please help me with this question?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Remko I was able to display the notification.

I did a function to make its use simpler:

```
Public Function Notify(ByVal title As String, ByVal msg As String, _
                    Optional ByVal notification_icon As String = "Info", _
                    Optional ByVal app As String = "excel", _
                    Optional ByVal duration As Integer = 10)
                    
'Parameters:
'    title (str):Notification title
'    msg (str):Notification message
'    notification_icon (str):Notification icon. Available options are: Info, Error and Warning
'    app (str):Process name of app you want to be display in the system tray icon
'    duration (int):Duration of notification in seconds

Const PSpath    As String = "powershell.exe"

Dim WsShell     As Object: Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim strCommand  As String

If notification_icon <> "Info" And notification_icon <> "Error" And notification_icon <> "Warning" Then
    notification_icon = "Info"
End If

strCommand = """" & PSpath & """ -Command " & Chr(34) & "& { "
strCommand = strCommand & "Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notification = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $path = (Get-Process -id (get-process " & app & ").id).Path"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notification.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path)"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notification.BalloonTipIcon  = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::" & notification_icon & ""
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notification.BalloonTipText = '" & msg & "'"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notification.BalloonTipTitle = '" & title & "'"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notification.Visible = $true"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notification.ShowBalloonTip(" & duration & ")"
strCommand = strCommand & " }" & Chr(34)

WsShell.Run strCommand, 0, False

End Function

Public Sub Notify_Examples()

Notify "Insert Title Here", "Insert Your Message Here"
Notify "Insert Title Here", "Insert Your Message Here", "Warning"
Notify "Insert Title Here", "Insert Your Message Here", "Error", "outlook"

End Sub
```

I'd like to make and extra observation. Nothing happens when leave the PSpath = "powershell.exe". I guess this is due to the fact my user is not an admin. I was able to bypass this by copying the powershell.exe to my documents and altering the PSpath to "C:\Users\my_user\Documents\powershell.exe". Maybe this is the case for you too...

Comment: [Visual Basic NotifyIcon for Taskbar Notification](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/745204/visual-basic-notifyicon-for-taskbar-notification)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist doing this with PowerShell the following code works:

```
Public Sub Notify_Test()

Dim WsShell     As Object: Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim strCommand  As String

strCommand = "powershell.exe -Command " & Chr(34) & "& { "
strCommand = strCommand & "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms')"
strCommand = strCommand & "; [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing')"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify.visible = $true"
strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify.showballoontip(10,'New Chat!','You have received New Chat!',[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)"
strCommand = strCommand & " }" & Chr(34)
WsShell.Run strCommand

End Sub
```

It will of course briefly flash a console (powershell) window

Comment: Thank you @Remko ! It worked. I don't insist in doing this with PowerShell, i just figure out it would be simpler like this. And if you know a better way to do this I actually would like to know

Comment: Note that in my case replacing `WsShell.run` with  `Shell strCommand, vbHide` saved me of the annoying powershell window flashing on the screen.

Comment: Also curious for a more VBA centric solution!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @remko's answers I also added the ability to launch a command/URL when clicking the notification:

```vb
Public Sub showBalloonTipVBA(ByVal title As String, ByVal msg As String, ByVal click_url As String, ByVal duration_in_seconds As Integer)

    Dim WsShell     As Object: Set WsShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim strCommand  As String
    
    strCommand = "powershell.exe -Command " & Chr(34) & "& { "
    strCommand = strCommand & "[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms')"
    strCommand = strCommand & "; [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing')"
    strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon"
    strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information"
    strCommand = strCommand & "; $notify.visible = $true"
    strCommand = strCommand & "; register-objectevent $notify BalloonTipClicked BalloonClicked_event -Action {cmd /c Start `\""`\"" `\""" & click_url & "`\""} | Out-Null"
    strCommand = strCommand & "; try { $notify.showballoontip(" & Str(duration_in_seconds) & "000,'" & title & "','" & msg & "',[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)"
    strCommand = strCommand & "; wait-event -timeout " & Str(duration_in_seconds) & " -sourceIdentifier BalloonClicked_event > $null } finally { $notify.Dispose() } "
    strCommand = strCommand & " }" & Chr(34)
    
    ' Debug.Print strCommand
    
    WsShell.Run strCommand, 0 ' Run without command line window

End Sub
```